# How to display data from a ListBox like a a comboGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using `@Html.ListBoxFor`in a form for the user to choose a Company... The company object has a lot of properties to it, for example: Name, ContactPerson, PhoneNumber, address etc.... I want to be able to display the data like a combo-grid so the information should be clear. I used the `Jquery sumoselect plugin` for all the other listboxes on my View. In other words, I want to be able to show more columns from the table in an organized fashion, but it should still be like a dropdown-multi-select...  How can I do that? thanks in advance.

This is what I have now:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCompanyList, new MultiSelectList(Model.Companies, "Id","CompanyName", Model.SelectedCompanyList), new {@class = "listbox"})
```

but I want to show more columns than only the name...

Comment: You have image of what you actually need?

Comment: Did you consider a custom HTML helper?

Comment: @User3250: I need something like a table, like a combo-grid. Instead of a list with all the company names, I want to display a dropdown of a  list of a few columns from the table... Thanks.

Comment: @Core-One: Which custom Html helper? I'm very new to all of this, can you give me an example or explain what you mean? thanks a lot.

Comment: I generally use [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) you may check this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/) for other plugins which might suit you

Comment: @User3250: Thanks. I want the dropdown should look more like a Grid-View; something like  a table with column headers and the user can choose multiple rows...

Comment: try EasyUI's combogrid:  http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboGrid